# How to do a async HTTP request inside an Angular2 loop/map and modify the original loop array?

Tags: asynchronous, angular, observable, angular2-http

New to Angular2 here and wondering how to do this async request on array pattern (not so sure about the pattern name).

So let's say I use Angular2's `Http` to get a YouTube Playlist that contains `videoId` in each return item. Then I need to loop through this item with the `videoId` and do another request to YouTube to get the individual video information. This can be another common HTTP request, get the list then loop through the list and get the details of every individual item.

```js
let url = [YouTube API V3 list url]
let detailUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics';

this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        let newArray = data.items.map(entry => {

            let videoUrl = detailUrl + '&id=' + entry.id.videoId + 
                                       '&key=' + this.googleToken;

            this.http.get(videoUrl)
                .map(videoRes => videoRes.json())
                .subscribe(videoData => {
                     console.log(videoData);

                     //Here how to I join videoData into each item inside of data.items. 
                });
    });
});
```

So the above code does work. But I still have these two questions:

1. How do I join the `videoData` back to `data.items` and make sure the correct item inside the `data.items` is joined with the correct `videoData` (the `videoData` that is using the `entry.id.videoId` of the related item inside `data.items`) and create that new `newArray`?
2. How do I know when everything is done and do something based on all the data after all the async requests have finished?
3. The newArray keep the same order of the first HTTP request. As the first HTTP hit the YouTube search list API with order by viewCount. Simply nest observable like above will not keep the original order.

**UPDATE**

With inoabrian solution, I can successfully achieve the above three points. But when I call the myvideoservice again (like changing the url as new NextPageToken), the Subject - this._videoObject has 2 observers. And load again, it has 3 observers and so on. I need a way to reset the Subject to have only 1 observers so I won't have duplicate videos. Is it a best practice way to clear/reset subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// You need to set up a subject in your sevice
private _videoObject = new Subject < any > ();
videoDataAnnounced$ = this._videoObject;


let url = [YouTube API V3 list url]
let detailUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics';

this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.cache = data.items;
        data.items.forEach(entry => {
            let videoUrl = detailUrl + '&id=' + entry.id.videoId + '&key=' + this.googleToken;
            this.http.get(videoUrl)
                .map(videoRes => videoRes.json())
                .subscribe(videoData => {
                    // This will announce that the full videoData is loaded to what ever component is listening.
                    this._videoObject.next(videoData);
                });
        });
    });



// In your constructor for your component you can subscribe to wait on the data being loaded.
public newVideos: any[] = [];
constructor(private myServiceToLoadVideos: myvideoservice) {
    let self = this;
    this.myServiceToLoadVideos.videoDataAnnounced$.subscribe((video) => {
        // Here you could loop through that
        self.myServiceToLoadVideos.cache.map(d => {
            if (d.id == video.id) {
                // Here you have the old data set without the details which is (d) from the cached data in the service.
                // And now you can create a new object with both sets of data with the video object
                d.snippet = video.items[0].snippet;
                d.statistics = video.items[0].statistics;
                d.contentDetails = video.items[0].contentDetails;
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(d);
            }
        });
        if(this.posts.length == this.cache.length){
          this.posts.sort(function(l,r){
            // if l is < r then it will return a negative number
            // else it will return a positive number.
            // That is how this sort function works
            return l.viewCount - r.viewCount;
          });

          // Here you will have all of the data and it will be sorted in order.
        }
    });
}
```

> UPDATE
>       -- -- --
>
> ```
> The Subject is an observable - http: //reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html
>
>     When you listen to the Subject it is not like q.all it will complete one by one until they complete.
>
> The cache in the service call is just to keep track of the playlist.
> Then when you receive the details in the constructor you can match them back up and keep order with the cache.
>
> Q: "And when subscribe to the subject as in your code, the result is when ALL the "
> next " in _videoObject finished, right?"
> A: No, when each individual finishes you will get once at a time.
> ```
>
> JS Sort -
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Could you just do this at the end?


this.posts.sort((l,r) =>{
  return l.viewCount - r.viewCount;
})

Comment: I added the sorting to where the data would  be complete.

Comment: well it is completed now when posts and cache are the same size then you sort the complete list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116526/discussion-between-inoabrian-and-hugh-hou).

Comment: Found a new issue using your solution: If I wrapped the first part of the code inside a function called fetchData() in the service and the second part of the code inside loadSettings() in the component. And inside the service, I am changing the url with NextPageToken to get the next 10 videos from YT.  When I call loadSettings() with a load more btn, which will call this.myServiceToLoadVideos.fetchData() again, the this._videoObject contains 2 observers. If I click load more btn again, it contain 3 observers. So I will have duplicated videos. How do I reset the Subject when I call it again?

Comment: The second part is supposed to listen to the response which is setup inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that you only need the modified data, once all the sub-requests are completed**

This is what you'll need

```ts
this.http.get(url) // original request
      .map(res => res.json())  // extract json from response
      .switchMap(data => {  // take-over the original data and make the subsribers wait for sub-requests to complete

        let modifiedRequest = new Subject(); // observable to to publish modified data, once all sub-requests are completed

        let allSubRequests = data.items.map(entry => {  // array of sub-requests

          let videoUrl = detailUrl + '&id=' + entry.id.videoId +
                         '&key=' + this.googleToken;

          return this.http.get(videoUrl)
            .map(videoRes => videoRes.json())  // extract json for every sub-request
            .map(videoJson => {  // modify the original 'data' object with the data in videoJson (I don't know the format, so can't tell how-to)

              // modify your "data" here

              return videoJson; // let the flow continue
            });
        });

        let mergedSubRequests = Observable.range(0, 1).merge.apply(null, allSubRequests);  // merge all sub-requests to know when will all are completed

        mergedSubRequests.subscribe(  // subscribe to merged observable
          (d) => {}, // data from every sub-request, we don't need it
          (e) => {}, // error from every sub-request, handle it as you want
          () => {   // success, called after all sub-requests are completed
              modifiedRequest.next(data);  // send out the modified data
              modifiedRequest.complete();  // complete the temprary observable
              }
        );

        return modifiedRequest; // provide the observable with modified data, to subscribers of orginal request, they will not know the difference
      });
```

---

**Required Imports:**

```ts
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/range';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

*Hope it helps, not tested though :)*

Comment: This part lost me: let mergedSubRequests = Observable.range(0, 1).merge.apply(null, allSubRequests);

Comment: Also your use of switchmap. Can out explain more why you use switchmap here? As switchmap cancel the pervious observable, right?

Comment: I just test your code and it is not working for me... I put a console.log(data) after the switchMap and there is no console log out. And I put a console.log(videoJson) before the return videoJson and also no log. The entire code seem block by switchMap...no idea what is going wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
let addDetail = (entry) => {
  let videoUrl = detailUrl + '&id=' + entry.id.videoId + 
                '&key=' + this.googleToken;

  return this.http.get(videoUrl)
    .map(videoRes => Object.assign({videoData: videoRes.json()}, entry)
};

let maxConcurrentRequest = 1;
let source = this.http.get(url)
  // any of mergeMap, concatMap, switchMap... will do
  .mergeMap(res => Observable.from(res.json().items))
  .mergeMap(addDetail, null, maxConcurrentRequest);
source.subscribe( /* Do anything you wish */ );
```

Now each item that `source` emits is an entry in the playlist merged with its videoData in `videoData` field (your first question)

`source` completes when everything is done (your second question)

you can control the number of maximum concurrent requests to `detailUrl` by setting `maxConcurrentRequest`. With `maxConcurrentRequest` = 1, `source` will emit items in the same order as they are in the playlist. If you don't care about order, increase `maxConcurrentRequest` for faster speed

Comment: I do need to preserve the original order of the data.items as the video list is sorted based on viewCount. So I want the same order of the video detail. But I don't quite get your code as I am very new to observable. What is the object.assign? And the mergeMap?

Comment: mergeMap = flatMap, see http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html and http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap
Object.assign is a function to "merge" objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

You already have access within the `.map` function to `entry` you should be able to just put another value onto it using dot notation. so do something like this:

```
let url = [YouTube API V3 list url]
let detailUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics';

this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        let newArray = data.items.map(entry => {

            let videoUrl = detailUrl + '&id=' + entry.id.videoId + 
                                       '&key=' + this.googleToken;

            this.http.get(videoUrl)
                .map(videoRes => videoRes.json())
                .subscribe(videoData => {
                     console.log(videoData);

                     entry.videoData = videoData;

                     //Here how to I join videoData into each item inside of data.items. 
                });
    });
});
```