# Dependent and parallel requests through Observables in ng2

Tags: angular, observable

I am putting together an application that displays information about 'Modyules' (on a course) that it has to pull via two http.gets (I have no control over the apis unfortunately):

1. Gets the list of Modyule.ids - need to store the id
2. For each Modyule.id another http.get to get the Modyule.name

In my modyule.component.ts, I have:

```
this.modyuleService.getModyules()
     .subscribe(
          modyules => this.modyules = modyules,
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
     );
```

In my modyule.service.ts, I have:

```
getModyules (): Observable<Modyule[]> {
        return this.http.get(listOfModyuleIdsUrl + '.json')
            .map(this.getModyulesDetails)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

But the getModyuleDetails is where I am struggling. This is where I have got to so far, mainly based on:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

and looking at, but not seeing how I can apply:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676917/2235210

```
private getModyulesDetails = (res: Response) => {  // instance method for defining function so that the this.http below refers to the class.
    let listOfModyules = res.json();
    let modyulesToReturn = [];

    for (let individualModyule of listOfModyules){
        let tempModyule = new Modyule;
        tempModyule.id = individualModyule.id;

        this.http.get(individualModyuleUrl + individualModyule.id + '.json')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json()))
            .subscribe(res => {
                tempModyule.name = res.name
                modyulesToReturn.push(tempModyule);
            });
        }
    return modyulesToReturn;      
}
```

Now this is working on my local machine where I have mocked up the .json responses as static .json files..but, when I'm dealing with the real api, I can't rely on the http.gets in the for loop to have completed before returning modyulesToReturn.

I've had a couple of attempts at forkJoin but don't see how I can combine this with the requirement to capture the Modyule.id from the first http.get.

I'd be very grateful for any pointers for how to do parallel requests which depend on an initial request and yet be able to combine data from both.

EDIT in reponse to discussion with @Matt and @batesiiic:

So, picking up on @batesiiic's suggested rewrite of getModyulesDetails to return a Subject, the problem I can't get my head around is how to populate the Modyule.id in the first call and then the Modyule.name in the second call (which doesn't return any reference to the Modyule.id) ie:

```
private getModyulesDetails = (res: Response) => {  // instance method for defining function so that the this.http below refers to the class.
    let listOfModyules = res.json();
    let modyulesToReturn = [];
    let calls = [];

    for (let individualModyule of listOfModyules){
        /* I REALLY NEED TO POPULATE Modyule.id HERE */
        calls.push(
            this.http.get(individualModyuleUrl + individualModyule.id + '.json')
                .map((res: Response) => res.json()))
        );
    }

    var subject = new Subject<Modyules[]>();

    Observable.zip.apply(null, calls).subscribe((modyules: Modyules[]) => {
        var modyulesToReturn = [];
        modyules.forEach(modyule => {
            let tempModyule = new Modyule;
            /*I COULD POPULATE Modyle.name HERE BUT IT WON'T MATCH THE Modyule.id SET ABOVE - EXCEPT BY LUCK*/
            modyulesToReturn.push(tempModyule);
        }
        subject.next(modyulesToReturn);
    });

    return subject;      
}
```

I think I need to make the calls one by one in the for loop but somehow wait until they have all responded before returning the modyulesToReturn?

Answer (score 1):

If one request depends on data returned by another request (in your case you need the `module.id` before you can make a call to `module.name` or its details), you should start the dependent request in the callback of the first request.

```
this.modyuleService.getModyules()
 .subscribe(
      modyules => {
        // start your request(s) for the details here
      },
      error =>  ...
 );
```

Furthemore, you use the following construct:

```
getModyulesDetails() {
  // this is what you want to return
  let modyulesToReturn = [];

  for (let individualModyule of listOfModyules){
    //.. you are starting asynchronous tasks here,
    // and fill your modyulesToReturn in their callbacks
  }

  // instantly return the variable that is filled asynchrously
  return modyulesToReturn;  
}
```

This cannot work the way you intend to. The http requests in the for loop are asynchronous, i.e. they get started but the current thread will not wait until they finish but proceed with the next iteration of the `for loop`. When you return from your method it is very likely that the callbacks in your subscription have not been called yet. When they do, you have already returned your (possibly) empty array of `modyulesToReturn`.

Thus, you must not return synchronously. Instead, you should offer a method that returns an `Observable`, too, which fires everytime when you receive another `modyule` detail. The components that need those details would subscribe themselves to that `Observable` and receive updates asynchronously, as well.

If you start using asynchronous tasks you need to push that "design" down to your components.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I am probably misunderstanding but is this not what I am effectively doing by collecting the details in calling getModyulesDetails in the map callback (in the service)? I'm still not sure how I would make the getModyules wait until getModyuleDetails (even if inserted where you suggest as a service method, with its own subscribe callback) had returned...does a .subscribe callback which contains another .subscribe callback have to wait until the second subscribe has been called?

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Your explanation is very clear. batesiiic + e.g http://stackoverflow.com/a/38156976/2235210 suggest using Rx.Subjects but I don't really understand how this works. Am I right in reading what you're saying as being that I should avoid these sorts of dependent/chained requests within a single component and instead create e.g ModyuleDetailComponent which observes an Observable getModyulesDetails method? In which case how do I let ModyuleDetailComponent know that ModyuleComponent has finished getting the list of Modyule.ids so I can e.g. @Input() them to ModyuleDetailComponent?

Comment: It depends. batesiiic's approach is to bundle everything, so that the Subject/Observable would fire once. If you subscribe to it you would get the entire list of details. The other way is to send the details to your component piece by piece, everytime you get a response from the server. Then the Subject/Observable would fire many times. This could be useful if you have a large number of modyules and you'd rather show the user the first 10 than to let him wait until all (let's say) 1000 have been loaded. - batesiiic's code provides the idea to realize both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use [`Observable.zip`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) to handle the multiple calls that are happening at once. It would require making your `getModyules` call to return a Subject (of some kind) which you could then call next on once the zip is complete.

```
getModyules (): Observable<Modyule[]> {
    var subject = new Subject<Modyule[]>();
    this.http.get(listOfModyuleIdsUrl + '.json')
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.getModyulesDetails(result)
                .subscribe(modyules => {
                    subject.next(modyules);
                });
        }, error => subject.error(error));

    return subject;
}
```

And details call becomes something like (zip returns a collection of all the returns, which I believe would be `Modyules[]` in your case):

```
private getModyulesDetails = (res: Response) => {  // instance method for defining function so that the this.http below refers to the class.
    let listOfModyules = res.json();
    let modyulesToReturn = [];
    let calls = [];

    for (let individualModyule of listOfModyules){
        calls.push(
            this.http.get(individualModyuleUrl + individualModyule.id + '.json')
                .map((res: Response) => res.json()))
        );
    }

    var subject = new Subject<Modyules[]>();

    Observable.zip.apply(null, calls).subscribe((modyules: Modyules[]) => {
        var modyulesToReturn = [];
        modyules.forEach(modyule => {
            let tempModyule = new Modyule;
            //populate modyule data
            modyulesToReturn.push(tempModyule);
        }
        subject.next(modyulesToReturn);
    });

    return subject;      
}
```

I made these changes in the browser, so I apologize for syntax errors, but I think the general idea would solve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand this - the docs on Subject aren't making it much clearer to me e.g: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/subject/index.html. I can see that a Subject is something that is both an Observer and an Observable, but, since nothing is subscribing to the Subject in getModyules, why would getModyules not just return an empty subject if getModyulesDetails doesn't complete in time...

Comment: Thanks batesiiic. Having discussed this with @Matt, it sounds as if this is the right approach (for 10 or so Modyules) and it's beginning to make more sense. However, the bit I can't work out is how to get the individualModyule.id, read in the first call, associated with the correct modyule as returned in the .zipped call...there's no reference to the individualModyule.id in the json returned and the calls in the .zip could come back in any order...I'll edit my question in a minute to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to both @batesiiic, @Matt (I've upvoted both your answers) and a useful hour (a drop in the ocean compared to the two long evenings and the whole of a Saturday I've spent on this already!) spent watching [Angular University](https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular2-how-to-setup-an-http-request-sequence-using-the-rxjs-switchmap-operator), I have a working solution (so far anyway!). .switchMap to chain two requests together, passing the Observable from the first into the second, @batesiiic's brilliant Subject idea (and forkJoin - I couldn't get zip to work) and the realisation that I could get my Modyule.id in the dependent request by looking at the response object itself!

In modyule.component.ts in ngOnInit():

```
this.modyuleService.getModyules()
        .switchMap(modyules =>this.modyuleService.getModyulesDetails(modyules)) 
        .subscribe(
            modyules => {
                this.modyules = modyules  
                },
           error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

and in module.service.ts:

```
getModyules (): Observable<Modyule[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.listOfModyuleIdsUrl)
        .map(this.initialiseModyules)
        .catch(this.handleError);            
}

private initialiseModyules(res: Response){
    let body = res.json();
    let modyulesToReturn = [];
    for (let individualModyule of listOfModyules){
        let tempModyule = new Modyule;
        tempModyule.id = individualModyule.id;
        modyulesToReturn.push(tempModyule);
        }
    }
    return modyulesToReturn;
}

getModyulesDetails (modyules:Modyule[]): Observable<Modyule[]> {
    let calls  = [];

    for (let modyule of modyules){
        calls.push(
            this.http.get(this.individualModyuleUrl + modyule.id + '.json')
            );
    }

    var subject = new Subject<Modyule[]>();   

    Observable.forkJoin(calls).subscribe((res: any) => {
        for (let response of res){
            //Note this is a really very awkward way of matching modyule with a id assigned in getModyules (above) with the correct response from forkJoin (could come back in any order), by looking at the requested url from the response object
            let foundModyule = modyules.find(modyule=> {
                let modyuleUrl = this.individualModyuleUrl + modyule.id + '.json';
                return modyuleUrl === response.url;
            });
            let bodyAsJson = JSON.parse(response._body);
            foundModyule.name = res.name;
            }
        subject.next(modyules);
    });

    return subject;
}
```

Hope that helps someone else. However, still can't help feeling that there ought to be some way to not return from multiple calls to get details until they have all finished, without having to resort to the free for all of .forkJoin or .zip where you no longer have a relationship with the calling modyule except by looking at the response.url...

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond for a while there. I was out on vacation away from any kind of computer :). Glad you got it working. As a note to one of the questions that came up around `Observable.zip` with respect to the ordering, I believe it always sends you the response in the order of the collection of the calls. For example: Call A, B and C all get zipped (in that order as an array passed in) and the result will be sent as an array of response [A, B, C]. I've used this in a few areas already that are very dependent on the responses data being in the correct order.

Comment: No problem at all and thanks - zip does sound very useful - I'll have another go to see if I can get it working. Anyone looking at this but wanting to query the same url with dependent requests might also be interested in the extract behaviour mentioned by @Thierry Templier in this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38814277/2235210. This appears to allow recursion and conditions on that recursion but I haven't tested yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do a similar thing, where I must make a request for an authentication token before I can make any of a variety of follow-on requests.

I wanted to expose an "ApiService.Get(url)" for this, with all of the work needed to get & use the token hidden from higher level callers, but still only perform the call to get the token once.

I ended up with this kind of thing...

```typescript
export class ApiService {
  private apiToken: string;
  private baseHeaders: Headers;
  private tokenObserver: ReplaySubject<Response>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.tokenObserver = null;
    try {
      // set token if saved in local storage
      let apiData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('apiData'));
      if (apiData) {
        this.apiToken = apiData.apiToken;
      }
      this.baseHeaders = new Headers({
        'Accept-encoding': 'gzip',
        'API-Key': 'deadbeef-need-some-guid-123456789012',
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  private requestHeaders(): Headers {
    if (this.apiToken) {
      this.baseHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.apiToken);
    }
    return this.baseHeaders;
  }

  private getToken(): Observable<Response> {
    if (this.tokenObserver == null) {
      this.tokenObserver = new ReplaySubject<Response>();
      this.http.get('/newtoken', this.requestHeaders())
        .subscribe(
          this.tokenObserver.next,
          this.tokenObserver.error,
          this.tokenObserver.complete,
        );
    }
    return this.tokenObserver.asObservable();
  }

  private isApiTokenValid():boolean {
    console.log("Pretending to check token for validity...");
    return !!this.apiToken;
  }

  // Get is our publicly callable API service point
  //
  // We don't accept any options or headers because all
  // interface to our API calls (other than auth) is through
  // the URL.    
  public Get(url: string): Observable<Response> {
    let observer: Subject<Response> = new Subject<Response>();
    try {
      if (this.authTokenValid()) {
        this.getRealURL(observer, url);
      } else {
        this.GetToken().subscribe(
          (v) => this.getRealURL(observer, url),
          observer.error,
          // ignore complete phase
        );
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Get: error: " + e);
    }
    return observer.asObservable();
  }

  private getRealURL(observer: Subject<Response>, url: string): void {
    try {
      this.http.get(url, {headers: this.requestHeaders()})
        .subscribe(
          observer.next,
          observer.error,
          observer.complete,
        );
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("GetRealURL: error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

With this in place, calls to my API come down to:

```typescript
this.api.Get('/api/someurl')
  .subscribe(this.handleSomeResponse)
  .catch(this.handleSomeError);
```